# Notification workitem completing without polling on v3

Tags: c#, autodesk-designautomation

it seems that there is a way to achieve non polling mechanism to get the completion of a workitem as said on this page : https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/basics/
But I can't find a way to specify it using the api. What am I supposed to define in the workitem to have a callback on a specific endpoint?

This is what I already have :

```
var workITem = new WorkItem
            {
                ActivityId = Services.ForgeService.CleanActivityId,
                Arguments = new Dictionary<string, IArgument>
                {
                    {
                        "dwg",
                        new XrefTreeArgument
                        {
                            Url = inputUrl,
                            Verb = Verb.Get
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "results",
                        new XrefTreeArgument
                        {
                            Verb = Verb.Put,
                            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                {"Authorization", $"Bearer {token}"}
                            },
                            Url = outputUrl
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Romain,

Please go through the [LearnForge](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels) tutorial

```
string callbackUrl = "Your Callback Url";
    WorkItem workItemSpec = new WorkItem()
    {
        ActivityId = activityName,
        Arguments = new Dictionary<string, IArgument>()
        {
            { "inputFile", inputFileArgument },
            { "inputJson",  inputJsonArgument },
            { "outputFile", outputFileArgument },
            { "onComplete", new XrefTreeArgument { Verb = Verb.Post, Url = callbackUrl } }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. My bad for not clicking on this link from the github page. I was sticking with the design automation guide.